# How to make all other audio player stop when new is played?(Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im making a website around playing my music in Angular and i want to make other audio players stop when new is played.Anyone have a script for that?

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="{{ image }}" alt="Default Grey Box" class="mb-3" />
  <h3>{{ header }}</h3>
  <p>{{ description }}</p>
  <audio  title="{{ header }}" type="audio/mp3" preload="metadata" controls="true" src='{{ audioref }}' > Radio {{ header }} </audio>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid-box',
  templateUrl: './grid-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid-box.component.css']
})
export class GridBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() key: number;
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() description: string;
  @Input() image: string;
  @Input() audioref: string;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are playing new `audio`, you may trigger an event. In that event handler access `audio` element and explicitly call `pause()` on other `audio` elements.

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
  var players = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  [...players].forEach(player => {
    if(e.target != player){
      player.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a demo:

```html
<audio controls="true" id="a1"
src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"></audio>
<audio controls="true" id="a1"
src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3"></audio>
<audio controls="true" id="a1"
src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3"></audio>
<script>
var players = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
Array.from(players).forEach(player => {
    player.addEventListener('play', playHandler)
});
function playHandler(e) {
    [...players].forEach(player => {
        if (e.target != player) {
            player.pause();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: im getting an error                                                                                                  
ERROR in src/app/app-shell/radiostacje/grid-box/grid-box.component.ts(26,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'players'.

Comment: Forgot to add the line to get `audio` elements and assign to `players` variable. Added that in the answer. Please check.

Comment: Yeah it works but one more question how can i solve this? error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAudioElement>'.

Comment: Use `[...players].forEach()`

Comment: sorry for taking time but i have another error                                                                    error TS2461: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAudioElement>' is not an array type.      Typescript is weird.

Comment: You can do `Array.from(players).forEach(player => {})` or `[...players].forEach(player => {})`. Please see the demo added to the answer. I have shown both.